# Subset of all invertible elements is a group

Tags: group-theory

Let $S$ be a set with an associative law of composition and with an identity element. Show that the subset $S^*$ $\subset$ $S$ consisting of all invertible elements is a group.

Attempt at proving: We are given $e=1$ $\in$ $S$ and $(1^{-1})*(1)=1$ $\Rightarrow$ $1$ $\in$ $S^*$.

We defined $S^*$ to have an inverse for every one of its elements.

$\forall$ $a,b,c$ $\in$ $S^*$, $a,b,c$ $\in$ $S$ because $S^*$ $\subset$ $S$. $\Rightarrow$ $(ab)c = a(bc)$ $\Rightarrow$ The elements of $S^*$ are associative. $\Rightarrow$ $S^*$ has an associative law of composition.

First of all, are these three portions of the proof correct? Secondly, I still need to show the fourth condition (closure). How do I do this? The problem does not specify multiplication as the operation. Does this change things?

Comment: Composition in this context is the "multiplication" for the group. Now show if $a,b\in S^*$, $(ab)^{-1} = b^{-1}a^{-1}$ so that $ab\in S^*$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To show the final step, you need to compose two elements of $S^*$ and show that, that element has an inverse.  So let $a,b\in S^*$ and let $a^{-1},b^{-1}\in S^*$ be their respective inverses.  I need to show that $ab$ has an inverse.  But we have that,

$$(b^{-1}a^{-1})(ab)=b^{-1}(a^{-1}a)b=b^{-1}b=e $$

So we have $(ab)^{-1}=b^{-1}a^{-1}$.  This shows closure under your operation of composition, which I am just writing as juxtaposition for ease.  I think your other steps look good.